# how to intercept request from src='some server/video.mp4' in <video> tag with angular 6

Tags: video, angular6, angular-http-interceptors

if i have an element like

```
<video id="player1" class="video-js" #player>
  <source [src]="videoUrl" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

it will send a get request to that `videoUrl`. That request is not intercepted by angular interceptor. Is it possible to intercept is somehow?

Comment: did you find any answer for this ?